# Possible incorrect referencing

Tags: android, reference

I have been trying to fix this bug for 3-4 hours, and i don't really know what else to try...
Here is how the program should work:

When an alarm is set, it goes off and asks JSON parser class to fetch some numbers.

JSONParser class does exactly that, and when i put results into object and try to update the database, nothing is happening.

JSONParser returns the string with numbers, which indicates that it does actually do what it is supposed to, and also database works properly in different methods.

It is because of this, that i suspect that my reference to the object isn't good, and that is the reason that this isn't working, but i cannot see any mistakes... Here is the code:

Alarm class ( where the `Ticket` object is drawn from the database) :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    /*acquire power service manager*/
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"TAG");
    wl.acquire();


    boolean  boot = intent.getBooleanExtra("boot", false);

    if(boot==true){
        findTicketAndSetAlarm(context);
    }
    else{
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Bundle");
        UUID id = UUID.fromString(b.getString("Key"));
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        currentTicket = db.getTicket(id);

        if(Global.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(context, currentTicket,true,null);
            parser.execute("http://www.millipiyango.gov.tr/sonuclar/cekilisler/sayisal/20150228.json");
        }
        else{
            sendNotification(context,intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the JSONParser class `onPostExecute` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result == null){
            if(mNotification)
                Alarm.notifyUser(mContext, mTicket);
            else
                mActivity.notify(false);
        }
        else{
        try {

            int numbers[] = new int[6];

            numbers = getJSON(numbers,result); //GETS the numbers from REST service

            saveResultsToTicket(numbers); 

            String sResult = Global.getStringFromArray(numbers); //STRING WITH WORKING NUMBERS

            if(mNotification)
                Alarm.notifyUser(mContext, mTicket,sResult,mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.these_numbers_were_picked_));
            else
                mActivity.notify(true);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            if(mNotification)
                Alarm.notifyUser(mContext, mTicket);
            else 
                mActivity.notify(false);

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    private void saveResultsToTicket(int[] numbers) {

        mTicket.setResultNumbers(numbers);

        ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        rows = mTicket.getRows();
        Iterator<Row> i = rows.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Row r = i.next();
            if((r.checkNumbers(numbers)).length >= 3){
                mTicket.setWon(Global.WIN);
                return;
            }
        }
        mTicket.setWon(Global.LOSE);

        commit();

    }


    private void commit() {
        DBOperator dbOp = new DBOperator(mContext.getApplicationContext(), Global.UPDATE);
        dbOp.execute(mTicket);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, the method name `commit` is used in java, and Eclipse doesn't show any warning or error if by some chance you name your method exactly the same.
So method name was the problem i was facing...